# XML 2x the same siblings in xml, how do i get the second one?

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I have een xml feed, I'd like to get te categorie and the subcategorie from this line of the xml:

with:

```
cat = x.find('categories/category/cat/title').text
```

I only get the first one (`vibo's`) and also need (`Vibrator Speciaal`)

```
<categories>
<category>
<cat>
<id>1</id>
<title>Vibo's</title> //Need this one
</cat>
<cat>
<id>182</id>
<title>Vibrator Speciaal</title> //and need this one
</cat>
</category>
</categories>
```

Can't get it working as I want

Comment: use `find_all` instead of `find` - it gives list with all elements. And then use `for`-loop to get text from all elements. OR `cat_list[1]` to get second element from list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `BeautifulSoup` then you should use `find_all` instead of `find`.

```
cat = soup.find_all('title')
```

It gives list with all elements and then you can use `for`-loop

```
for item in cat:
    print(item.text)
```

or index or slice

```
print(cat[1].text)
```

---

**EDIT:** in other modules it may have name `findall`

```
text = """
<categories>
<category>
<cat>
<id>1</id>
<title>Vibo's</title> //Need this one
</cat>
<cat>
<id>182</id>
<title>Vibrator Speciaal</title> //and need this one
</cat>
</category>
</categories>
"""

# -----

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')

cat = soup.find_all('title')

for item in cat:
    print(item.text)

# OR
print(cat[1].text)

# -----

import lxml.etree

soup = lxml.etree.fromstring(text)

cat = soup.findall('.//title')

for item in cat:
    print(item.text)

# OR
print(cat[1].text)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this using lxml and XPath expression :

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse("yourXMLFile.xml")
for title in tree.xpath("/categories/category/cat/title"):
    print(title.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

and thank you for all of your quick answers!

This is working perfect for me right now! Thnks to your help

```
cat = x.findall('categories/category/cat/title')
print(blabla, blabla, blabla, cat[1].text)
print(blabla, blabla, blabla, cat[0].text)
```